# Manual UI scaling for non Unity environments

Tags: 14.04, window-manager, dpi

14.04 and Unity now offer UI Scaling. But what if I am not running Unity? In this case I am running Awesome Window Manager. How can I get my *applications* to scale the way they do when I am running Unity?

In other words: Is there any way to replicate this UI scaling setting in other desktop environments?:

[image]

I know I am on my own for things that are specific to my window manager, and I have solved those, but the applications don't scale nicely the way they do in Unity.

Comment: What do you mean by "UI scaling"? This http://www.webupd8.org/2014/02/unity-spread-gets-support-for-filtering.html ("live resize")?

Comment: as in http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-QzWKIzl7QpQ/U0-9Tx2s-SI/AAAAAAAAIPE/wOT5ywVJV_s/s1600/scale-menu_and-title-bars.jpg